# Any luck with mod_libpq under Apache 2.2 and/or win32?

Tags: apache, postgresql, apache2-module, apache-modules

Has anyone had luck compiling [mod_libpq](http://asmith.id.au/mod_libpq.html) for Apache 2?  I know there were some fairly major changes so the source might have to be updated, but has it been done already by someone?

Also, has it been compiled for win32 (either version of Apache, or another web server altogether?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written an updated version for Apache2.2 which can be downloaded from

http://asmith.id.au/source/mod_libpq2.c

However, it is my first attempt at writing a module for Apache2 and it is not debugged yet.

Previously I had no use for it as I was still using Apache1.3 but since I am now faced with retiring that old server I guess I'll have to finish off the new version.